# Subsetting a data.table using logical function by calling its string name

Tags: r, data.table

I have a function containing a logical expression to subset the rows of a `data.table`. I want to call this function by its name given by a character string and a vector of column names representing the function arguments as well (as similar to using `do.call`). However, I have no clue how to approach that intention.

In a simple, reproducible example:

```
#function with logical return value
myfunc <- function(mpg, cyl) {
  mpg/cyl > 7
}

#name of function
funcname <- "myfunc"

#vector of column names, corresponding to the function parameters
cols <- c("mpg", "cyl")

#data.table to be subsetted
dt <- setDT(copy(mtcars))
```

What I am looking for is a function to pass the variables `dt`, `funcname` and `cols` in order to obtain the following result as it is identical to `dt[mpg/cyl > 7, ]`:

```
#desired function
subsetfunc(dt, funcname, cols)

    mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
1: 32.4   4 78.7  66 4.08 2.200 19.47  1  1    4    1
2: 30.4   4 75.7  52 4.93 1.615 18.52  1  1    4    2
3: 33.9   4 71.1  65 4.22 1.835 19.90  1  1    4    1
4: 30.4   4 95.1 113 3.77 1.513 16.90  1  1    5    2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way

```
subsetfunc <- function(data, funcstring, colnms) {
   data[get(funcstring)(data[[colnms[1]]], data[[colnms[2]]])]


}
```

-testing

```
> subsetfunc(dt, funcname, cols)
     mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
   <num> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num>
1:  32.4     4  78.7    66  4.08 2.200 19.47     1     1     4     1
2:  30.4     4  75.7    52  4.93 1.615 18.52     1     1     4     2
3:  33.9     4  71.1    65  4.22 1.835 19.90     1     1     4     1
4:  30.4     4  95.1   113  3.77 1.513 16.90     1     1     5     2
```

---

Or use `do.call`

```
subsetfunc <- function(data, funcstring, colnms) {
   
   data[data[, do.call(funcstring, .SD), .SDcols = colnms]]
}
```

-testing

```
> subsetfunc(dt, funcname, cols)
     mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
   <num> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num>
1:  32.4     4  78.7    66  4.08 2.200 19.47     1     1     4     1
2:  30.4     4  75.7    52  4.93 1.615 18.52     1     1     4     2
3:  33.9     4  71.1    65  4.22 1.835 19.90     1     1     4     1
4:  30.4     4  95.1   113  3.77 1.513 16.90     1     1     5     2
```

Comment: Great, thanks! The `do.call` variant is the solution I was looking for as it works with a varying number of arguments.

Answer (score 3):

In case you are interested in exploring the `env` parameter in data.table version 1.14.3, here is an alternative approach:

```
subsetfunc <- function(dt,funcname,cols) {
  dt[f(c1, c2), env = list(f=funcname, c1=cols[1], c2=cols[2])]
}

subsetfunc(dt,funcname,cols)
```

Output:

```
    mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
1: 32.4   4 78.7  66 4.08 2.200 19.47  1  1    4    1
2: 30.4   4 75.7  52 4.93 1.615 18.52  1  1    4    2
3: 33.9   4 71.1  65 4.22 1.835 19.90  1  1    4    1
4: 30.4   4 95.1 113 3.77 1.513 16.90  1  1    5    2
```

Comment: So neat! Thanks for posting

Comment: What is actually important to notice as an advantage over akrun solution is that here, query will be substituted at start and will continue as being written by hand, letting (if any) optimization to happen. Like using indexes, redirecting order to forder, etc.

Comment: `verbose=TRUE` can be used to print prepared query

Comment: I didn't realize `verbose` was an option! excellent..